# Why does the code self destruct whenever I click the very top checkbox in KIVYMD DataTable, but it works fine when I normally press an option?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

```
MDDataTable(
        pos_hint={"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.4},
        size_hint=(0.9,0.5),
        check=True,
        rows_num = 7,
        use_pagination = True,
        column_data=[
            ("MVC", dp(30)),
            ("ID", dp(15))
        ],
        row_data = [
            ("Bakers Basin", "300"),
            ("Bayonee", "150"),
            ("Camden","150"),
            ("Cardiff","5"),
            ("Delanco","3"),
            ("Eatontown","3"),
            ("Edison","3"),
            ("Flemington","3"),
            ("Freehold","3"),
            ("Lodi","3"),
            ("Newark","3"),
            ("North Bergen","3"),
            ("Oakland","3"),
            ("Paterson","3"),
            ("Rahway","3"),
            ("Randolph","3"),
            ("Rio Grande","3"),
            ("Salem","3"),
            ("South Plainfield","3"),
            ("Toms River","3"),
            ("Vineland","3"),
            ("Wayne","3"),
            ("West Deptford","3")        
        ]
        
        )
```

Comment: what error do you get during `self destruction`?

Comment: If we copy/paste your example, it crashs, always make a working example on your post please.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].